# 400 Response code on post to hubspot form

Tags: guzzle, gravity-forms-plugin, hubspot

I am using a plugin on a WordPress website which is supposed to feed gravity forms submissions into hubspot however, on submission I get the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: POST https://forms.hubspot.com/uploads/form/v2/XXXXXX/97d44f1e-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-e4c453843854 resulted in a 404 Not Found response:`

I've nullified the URL.

I've searched this error and read through many, many GitHub threads but no seem of any use to me - they're all about other people's bespoke implementations. Can anybody here shed any light on this for me? Is there any more information I can post to allow anybody to help me investigate deeper?

Answer (score 0):

Some temp fixes I've seen circulate:

1) On your Hubspot forms, make sure they are using Thank You messages and NOT the redirect to page feature (neither are actually functional if you are using only this plugin making API requests and not using for form embed code etc provided by HubSpot)

2) Save / update your forms in HubSpot

Since doing the above (there was a mixture of the two in our case, we have not caught any further errors for the past couple days)  Jury is still out on what is the true issue behind this.

Details:

I hit this issue as well.  Guzzle is throwing the error after seeing the HS response.  This Guzzle client was not used in the older version of the plugin, so thinking that either the request was different in previous versions (prior to v3) or HubSpot was throwing a 404 response before and it was being ignored. Data (in my testing) is still posting correctly to the HubSpot API and shown/updated in the Contact record database.  But website users end up seeing a 500 error due to this issue.  (As a result the analytics scripts on the thank you page never get fired so we caught this seeing a drop in GA)  I'm assuming the plugin could be coded around this to ignore the exception, but still no idea why it is being provided as a response in the first place.